# JScorllPane Text flying from window

Tags: java, loops, stream, scroll, frame

I'm trying to make a `JFrame` appear that reads each line from a text file into a `JLabel` and places that `JLabel` into a `JScrollPane`, that `JScrollPane` is then added to the Container for my window. The content and labels are loaded, but with one problem, as soon as the window loads my `JScrollPane` zips up and out of the `Container` leaving me with a blank window. Any help? here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Helper extends JFrame{

String  filepath = "assets/help.txt";
Scanner reader;
Container contentpane;
JScrollPane scrp =  new JScrollPane(null);
JLabel line = new JLabel();
int align_x, align_y;
int window_width  = 700;
int window_height = 700;

public Helper(){ 
    setSize(window_height,window_width);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Electric Force Calculator Helper");
    scrp.setSize(window_height,window_width);
    scrp.setVisible(true);

    contentpane = getContentPane();
    reader = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filepath));

    align_x = 10;
    align_y = 10;

    while(reader.hasNextLine()){
        line = new JLabel(reader.nextLine());
        line.setBounds(align_x,align_y,window_width,20);
        scrp.add(line);
        align_y+=20;
    }
    contentpane.add(scrp);

}

public static void showHelpFrame(){
    Helper newHelper = new Helper();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line = new JLabel(reader.nextLine());` you are creating a new label each time here and then adding that label over the other label in the `JScrollPane` with `scrp.add(line);`

A better way to do this would be to use a `JList`, wrap the `JList` in a `JScrollPane` and then populate the list's data model with your lines of text.

```
DefaultListModel<String> lines = new DefaultListModel<String>();
JList l = new JList(lines);
JScrollPane scrp =  new JScrollPane(l);

while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.addElement(reader.nextLine());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Don't use JLabel. Use JList. OR, add all the JLabels to a separate JPanel first, then add it to the JSCrollPane.

I have some advices to give you.

1. Use more user friendly names for variables (These names are small. Do you really need to use underscore, rather than using camel case? It is up to you anyway)
2. Don't set everything visible even before you have done with the simplest GUI. Do visible stuff at the end of the constructor, wherever possible
3. You are extending the JFrame. So, make it visible. In here, you have called 
   setVisible(true) to the JScrollPane too, which is not necessary.
4. The easiest way of calling the getContentPane is, getContentPane().add(stuff). No need of creating a separate variable for that.
5. Initialize variables inside the constructor. Not before that, making it out side of everything. It is possible, but that doesn't mean it is OK.

Comment: Always glad to receive helpful tips, I'll keep these in mind from now on